# HttpwebRequest and response taking time

Tags: vb.net

**below code is taking 150 to 200 second to read data (actualy my response data is very large) 
Please give any alternate to resolve this problem.**

```
Protected Function PostXml(ByVal url As String, ByVal xml As String) As String     
    Dim strResult As String = String.Empty   
    Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml) 
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)     
    request.Method = "POST"    
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length    
    request.ContentType = "text/xml"   

    Using requestStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()    
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)    
    End Using    

    Using response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)   

         If response.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK Then   
                Dim message As String = [String].Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode)   
                Throw New ApplicationException(message)   

         Else   
                Dim reader As StreamReader = Nothing    
                Dim responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()    
                reader = New StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default)    
                **strResult = reader.ReadToEnd()  'Here is taking to much time**     
                response.Close()    
                responseStream.Close()     
                reader.Close()     
          End If     
    End Using
```

Comment: What's "very large"? Unless you've got a very fast link, large = slow.

Comment: I think you should clse your response all the times, even if the StatusCode wasn't OK

Answer (score 0):

If you are controlling the response (the url points to a server that you manage), you can turn the GZIP compression on.

http://blog.arvixe.com/how-to-enable-gzip-on-iis7/